# What is known about the lower bound for the integers $n$ for which $n$ minus the first $k$ odd primes are $k$ composite numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

**Question edited in view of the comments below**

By Yamada's [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03409.pdf) we can conclude that if $n>e^{e^{36}}$ be an even number then it can always be written as the sum of a prime and a semi-prime.

My question is,

> **Question 1.** Let $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ be the first consecutive odd primes and $n>\max(e^{e^{36}},p_k)$ be an even integer such that for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, $n-p_i$ is composite. Is it possible that $n=p_r+p_sp_t$ (where $p_r,p_s,p_t\in\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$)?

Note that it is easy to show that if $n>p_k+p_k^2$ then the answer to the above question is "yes". So we only need to check whether the answer to the above question is "yes" for all even integers $n\le p_k+p_k^2$.

Following Gerhard Paseman's suggestion below I think a possible approach of attacking the problem will be to know more about the integers $n$ for which the hypothesis of the question holds. In this regard I have the following specific question in mind,

> **Question 2.** Let $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ be the first consecutive odd primes and $n$ be an even integer such that for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, $n-p_i$ is composite. What is known about the lower bound of $n$ (in terms of $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ satisfying such hypothesis?

Based upon my calculations, my best guess is that that $n> p_{k+1}$ but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: You mean that you look for triples which additionally satisfy $\max(q, r) >p$ abs ask whether they can be always found?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I am not sure I interpret your above comment correctly but it may happen that both $q=p_s$ and $r=p_t$ for some $s,t\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ but we also have $\max(p_s,p_t)>p_j$. It's not what I am asking. $\max(q,r)$ needs to satisfy the inequality $\max(q,r)>p_k$.

Comment: I am confused with quantifiers. Is $k$ fixed? If yes, how?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: The situation is this: First fix $k$ and choose $p_1,\ldots,p_k$. **then** choose $n$ such that $n>\max(e^{e^{36}},p_k)$ and then...

Comment: No it is not clear. What if $n=p_1+p_{k-1}p_{k-2}$?

Comment: If n is 1 + 3p_k, then obviously not, where as if n is at least 2(p_k)^2 then obviously yes.  Are you asking if there always is a representation of the desired form for certain n?  There probably is with all n not much bigger than 4p_k, but I do not know this to be true.  Gerhard "Not Sure Of The Question" Paseman, 2018.09.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: "If $n$ is $1 + 3p_k$, then obviously not" - the question is can there be any such $n$? More specifically how can you ascertain that $n-p_i$ will be composite for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$?

Comment: First, you changed the game on me, by adding the composite condition. Second, if such small n exists with n minus the primes composite, then my comment still holds. You need to ask the right question if you want the right comments.  Gerhard "Can't Go Back To Edit" Paseman, 2018.09.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Sorry, but I don't understand the part "you changed the game on me, by adding the composite condition". As far as I can recall the edit was made *before* your comment (in fact that's why I deleted it to see the defects in it).

Comment: No. The edit was made before the comment appeared to you. Your edit appeared to me after I posted the comment. I checked the history to make sure. Gerhard "Things Aren't What You See" Paseman, 2018.09.20.

Comment: Oh. Then sorry for the misunderstanding @GerhardPaseman.

Comment: These things happen. In my opinion, a better question would be to ask what is known about integers n with n minus the first k primes being k composite numbers. I think Silva may address this in his website on Goldbach decompositions.  Gerhard "Is This The Right Question?" Paseman, 2018.09.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Can you provide me the link of the website?

Comment: You can find it with a search on Goldbach and Tomas Oliviera e Silva. Gerhard "Still Not Cutting And Pasting" Paseman, 2018.09.20.